# Fail to connect to tensorboard launched from jupyter notebook sprawned from jupyterhub

Tags: tensorboard, jupyterhub

I follow the step to try to launch and connect to tensorboard on jupyterhub based jupyter notebook, I saw the tensorboard process but got connection timeout on notebook.

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what steps you have taken or add a link in your question to the tutorial you are following and explain if you have differed from the tutorial in any way.

Comment: I tried to run an example by this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started but got connecting timeout. Please note that this is JupyterHub, it seems trying to connect to the proxy/hub, but the tensorboard is running in the 'pod' when I try to run "%tensorboard --logdir logs/fit --host "0.0.0.0"' on notebook.

Comment: I have the same issue, have you figured it out?